# How to implement a tensor class for Kronecker-Produkt

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, product, tensor

Currently I came across an interesting article what's called the [Kronecker-Produkt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker-Produkt). At the same time I'm working on my neural network library.
So that my algorithm works, I need a tensor class, where I can get the product of two tensor's with an overloaded * operator.

Consider the following example/questions:

1. How to efficiently construct/store the nested matrices?
2. How to perform the product of two tensor's?
3. How to visualize tensor c as simply as possible?

My class 3 tensor which currently only supports 3 dimensions:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T>
class tensor {
public:
    const unsigned int x, y, z, s;

    tensor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, T val) : x(x), y(y), z(z), s(x * y * z) {
        p_data = new T[s];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++) p_data[i] = val;
    }

    tensor(const tensor<T> & other) : x(other.x), y(other.y), z(other.z), s(other.s) {
        p_data = new T[s];
        memcpy(p_data, other.get_data(), s * sizeof(T));
    }

    ~tensor() {
        delete[] p_data;
        p_data = nullptr;
    }

    T * get_data() {
        return p_data;
    }

    static tensor<T> * random(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z, T val, T min, T max) {
        tensor<T> * p_tensor = new tensor<T>(x, y, z, val);

        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 mt(rd());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(min, max);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < p_tensor->s; i++) {
            T rnd = dist(mt);
            while (abs(rnd) < 0.001) rnd = dist(mt);
            p_tensor->get_data()[i] = rnd;
        }

        return p_tensor;
    }

    static tensor<T> * from(std::vector<T> * p_data, T val) {
        tensor<T> * p_tensor = new tensor<T>(p_data->size(), 1, 1, val);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < p_tensor->get_x(); i++) p_tensor->set_data(i + 0 * p_tensor->get_x() * + 0 * p_tensor->get_x() * p_tensor->get_y(), p_data->at(i));

        return p_tensor;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & stream, tensor<T> & tensor) {
        stream << "(" << tensor.x << "," << tensor.y << "," << tensor.z << ") Tensor\n";

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tensor.x; i++) {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < tensor.z; k++) {
                stream << "[";

                for (unsigned int j = 0; j < tensor.y; j++) {
                    stream << std::setw(5) << roundf(tensor(i, j, k) * 1000) / 1000;
                    if (j + 1 < tensor.y) stream << ",";
                }

                stream << "]";

            }

            stream << std::endl;
        }

        return stream;
    }

    tensor<T> & operator +(tensor<T> & other) {
        tensor<T> result(*this);

        return result;
    }

    tensor<T> & operator -(tensor<T> & other) {
        tensor<T> result(*this);

        return result;
    }

    tensor<T> & operator *(tensor<T> & other) {
        tensor<T> result(*this);

        return result;
    }

    T & operator ()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int k) {
        return p_data[i + (j * x) + (k * x * y)];
    }

    T & operator ()(unsigned int i) {
        return p_data[i];
    }

private:
    T * p_data = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    tensor<double> * p_tensor_input = tensor<double>::random(6, 2, 3, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    tensor<double> * p_tensor_weight = tensor<double>::random(2, 6, 3, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    std::cout << *p_tensor_input << std::endl;
    std::cout << *p_tensor_weight << std::endl;

    tensor<double> p_tensor_output = *p_tensor_input + *p_tensor_weight;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to redo your post to be a single, technical focused question. You really have a large question here asking for someone to provide the implementation for a tensor class. You show no work of your own which is usually sufficient to persuade people to close a post.

Comment: are you looking for the technical details on an efficient implementation? Or more like an algorithm for the product?

Comment: More the efficient implementation.

Comment: Depending on the usage of the output tensor, flattening may be unnecessary and would bloat the amount of stored data. If all you want is a tensor product of 2 tensors and you are not going to modify it down the line and only use it then you should define the `Tensor` class as a pair of containers and implement lookup accessors to compute the entries on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Your first step is #2 -- and get it correct.

After that, optimize.

Start with a container `C<T>`.

Define some operations on it.  `wrap(T)` returns a `C<T>` containing that `T`.  map takes a `C<T>` and a function on `T` `U f(T)` and returns `C<U>`.  flatten takes a `C<C<U>>` and returns a `C<U>`.

Define `scale( T, C<T> )` which takes a `T` and a `C<T>` and returns a `C<T>` with the elements scaled.  Aka, scalar multiplication.

```
template<class T>
C<T> scale( T scalar, C<T> container ) {
  return map( container, [&](T t){ return t*scalar; } );
}
```

Then we have:

```
template<class T>
C<T> tensor( C<T> lhs, C<T> rhs ) {
  return flatten( map( lhs, [&](T t) { return scale( t, rhs ); } ) );
}
```

is your tensor product.  And yes, that can be your actual code.  I would tweak it a bit for efficiency.

(Note I used different terms, but I'm basically describing monadic operations using different words.)

After you have this, test, optimize, and iterate.

As for 3, the result of tensor products get large and complex, there is no simple visualization for a large tensor.

Oh, and keep things simple and store data in a `std::vector` to start.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tricks for efficient vectors i learned in class, but they should be equally good for a tensor.

Define an empty constructor and assignment operator. For example

```
tensor(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z), s(x * y * z) {
    p_data = new T[s];
}

tensor& operator=( tensor const& that ) {
    for (int i=0; i<size(); ++i) {
        p_data[i] = that(i) ;
    }
    return *this ;
}

template <typename T>
tensor& operator=( T const& that ) {
    for (int i=0; i<size(); ++i) {
        p_data[i] = that(i) ;
    }
    return *this ;
}
```

Now we can implement things like addition and scaling with deferred evaluation. For example:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class tensor_sum {
    //add value_type to base tensor class for this to work
    typedef decltype( typename T1::value_type() + typename T2::value_type() ) value_type ;

    //also add function to get size of tensor

    value_type operator()( int i, int j, int k ) const {
        return t1_(i,j,k) + v2_(i,j,k) ;
    }

    value_type operator()( int i ) const {
        return t1_(i) + v2_(i) ;
    }

    private:
    T1 const& t1_;
    T2 const& t2_;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
tensor_sum<T1,T2> operator+(T1 const& t1, T2 const& t2 ) {
    return vector_sum<T1,T2>(t1,t2) ;
}
```

This tensor_sum behaves exactly like any normal tensor, except that we don't have to allocate memory to store the result. So we can do something like this:

```
tensor<double> t0(...);
tensor<double> t1(...);
tensor<double> t2(...);
tensor<double> result(...); //define result to be empty, we will fill it later

result = t0 + t1 + 5.0*t2;
```

The compiler should optimize this to be just one loop, without storing intermediate results or modifying the original tensors. You can do the same thing for scaling and the kronecker product. Depending on what you want to do with the tensors, this can be a big advantage. But be careful, this isn't always the best option.

When implementing the kronecker product you should be careful of the of the ordering of your loop, try to go through the tensors in the order they are stored for cache efficiency.